# Image upload not Properly in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, varien-file-uploader

I want to upload image by custom module.In this module if i upload image the image name is

```
images (1).jpg
```

when image upload name saved it

```
images_1_.jpg
```

My code is

```
if (isset($_FILES['vendor_gallery']['name']) && $_FILES['vendor_gallery']['name'] != '') {
                try {
                    $path     = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'vendors' . DS . 'profile';
                     $fname    = $_FILES['vendor_gallery']['name'];
                    $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('vendor_gallery'); 

                    $uploader->setAllowCreateFolders(false); 
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false); 
                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
                    $uploader->save($path, $fname);                     
                }
                catch (Exception $e) {
                    echo 'Error Message: ' . $e->getMessage();
                }
            }


            if ($fname != "") {
                $data['vendor_gallery'] = $fname;
            }
            echo $fname;exit;

            try {
                $gallery = Mage::getModel('marketplace/gallery');
                if(isset($data['vendor_gallery']) && ($data['vendor_gallery'])!=''){
                $gallery->setData($data);
                $gallery->save();
                }
```

so how to do correct image name?

Comment: What is wrong with that image name? Magento has just normalised it.

Comment: i get image name  save in database images (1).jpg   and the path url images_1_.jpg                                                                                            so i get currupt image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the uploaded file by the following code.

```
$uploader->getUploadedFileName()
// Here $uploader is object of the Varien_File_Uploader class
```

This will return uploaded file name.

refer this [link](https://github.com/rmsundar1/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php#L363-l372)

Answer (score 0):

You can change name of the image after this point:

```
$fname    = $_FILES['vendor_gallery']['name'];
```

You can play with `$fname` and change it accordingly. But be careful with spaces, they are not accepted at all.